# UNION ALL or other ways to return first row of result-set

Tags: sql-server, performance, set-returning-functions, query-performance

I am writing a table valued function to geocode an address based on its Suburb, State and Postcode. I try to geocode the address using different methods, **in order of decreasing accuracy**:

1. Exact match on unique suburb-postcode-state combination
2. Exact match on unique suburb-postcode combination
3. Exact match on unique suburb-state combination
4. Exact match on unique postcode
5. Approximate match by non-unique Postcode, where all Suburbs with this Postcode are within 5 km of one another.

(I am working with a geographical region where Suburb-Postcode-State relationships are **all** many-to-many. In other words, one Suburb can have multiple postcodes; one postcode can have multiple suburbs and may exist in different states.)

Following is an extract from the table-valued function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [geocode].[tvfn_Customer_Suburb_From_Address]
(   
    @Suburb NVARCHAR(100),
    @State NVARCHAR(100),
    @Postcode NVARCHAR(100),
    @Country NVARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM (

            -- Unique suburb-postcode-state combinations
            SELECT   s.Suburb_DID
                    ,s.Suburb
                    ,s.State
                    ,s.Postcode
                    ,Geocode_DID = 4 -- Exact match by unique Postcode, Suburb and State
                    ,s.Geocode_Latitude
                    ,s.Geocode_Longitude
            FROM geocode.tSuburbs_XX s
            INNER JOIN [geocode].[tGeocode_Methods] gm
                ON s.Geocode_DID = gm.Geocode_DID

            WHERE s.[Is_Active] = 1
            AND s.[Suburb] = @Suburb
            AND s.[State] = @State
            AND s.[Postcode] = @Postcode
            -- Only suburbs that are geocoded with methods that can be used for geocoding customers
            AND gm.[Can_Use_For_VIP] = 1


            UNION ALL


            -- -- Unique suburb-postcode combinations
            SELECT   s.Suburb_DID
                    ,s.Suburb
                    ,s.State
                    ,s.Postcode
                    ,Geocode_DID = 3 -- Exact match by unique Postcode & Suburb
                    ,s.Geocode_Latitude
                    ,s.Geocode_Longitude
            FROM geocode.tSuburbs_XX s
                INNER JOIN [geocode].[tGeocode_Methods] gm
                    ON s.Geocode_DID = gm.Geocode_DID
            WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT *
                            FROM geocode.tSuburbs_XX
                            WHERE Is_Active = 1
                            AND Suburb = s.Suburb AND Postcode = s.Postcode
                            GROUP BY Postcode, Suburb
                            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                            )
            AND s.Is_Active = 1
            AND s.[Suburb] = @Suburb
            AND s.[Postcode] = @Postcode
            -- Only suburbs that are geocoded with methods that can be used for geocoding customers
            AND gm.[Can_Use_For_VIP] = 1


            UNION ALL


            -- Exact match by unique Suburb and State
            SELECT   s.Suburb_DID
                    ,s.Suburb
                    ,s.State
                    ,s.Postcode
                    ,Geocode_DID = 6 -- Exact match by unique Suburb and State
                    ,s.Geocode_Latitude
                    ,s.Geocode_Longitude
            FROM geocode.tSuburbs_XX s
                INNER JOIN [geocode].[tGeocode_Methods] gm
                    ON s.Geocode_DID = gm.Geocode_DID
            WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT *
                            FROM geocode.tSuburbs_XX
                            WHERE Is_Active = 1 AND Is_PO_Box = 0 -- Exclude PO Boxes
                            AND Suburb = s.Suburb AND Postcode = s.Postcode
                            GROUP BY Suburb, Postcode
                            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                            )
            AND s.Is_Active = 1
            AND s.[Suburb] = @Suburb
            AND s.[Postcode] = @Postcode
            -- Only suburbs that are geocoded with methods that can be used for geocoding customers
            AND gm.[Can_Use_For_VIP] = 1


            UNION ALL


            -- Exact match by unique Postcode
            SELECT   s.Suburb_DID
                    ,s.Suburb
                    ,s.State
                    ,s.Postcode
                    ,Geocode_DID = 2 -- Exact match by unique Postcode
                    ,s.Geocode_Latitude
                    ,s.Geocode_Longitude
            FROM geocode.tSuburbs_XX s
                INNER JOIN [geocode].[tGeocode_Methods] gm
                    ON s.Geocode_DID = gm.Geocode_DID
            WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT *
                            FROM geocode.tSuburbs_XX
                            WHERE Is_Active = 1
                            AND Postcode = s.Postcode
                            GROUP BY Postcode
                            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                            )
            AND s.Is_Active = 1
            AND s.[Postcode] = @Postcode
            -- Only suburbs that are geocoded with methods that can be used for geocoding customers
            AND gm.[Can_Use_For_VIP] = 1
            -- Perform this extra check to make sure we don't match a postcode in a wrong country
            AND (       @Country IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
                    OR  @State IN ('MMM', 'NNN', 'OOO', 'PPP')
                )


            UNION ALL


            -- Approximate match by non-unique Postcode, where all Suburbs with this Postcode are within 5 km of one another.
            SELECT   s.Suburb_DID
                    ,s.Suburb
                    ,s.State
                    ,s.Postcode
                    ,Geocode_DID = 5
                    ,s.Geocode_Latitude
                    ,s.Geocode_Longitude
            FROM [geocode].[tPostcode_Distances] pd
                INNER JOIN  geocode.tSuburbs_XX s
                    ON pd.Approx_Suburb_DID = s.Suburb_DID
                INNER JOIN [geocode].[tGeocode_Methods] gm
                    ON s.Geocode_DID = gm.Geocode_DID
            WHERE  s.Is_Active = 1
            AND pd.[Postcode] = @Postcode
            -- Only suburbs that are geocoded with methods that can be used for geocoding customers
            AND gm.[Can_Use_For_VIP] = 1
            -- Perform this extra check to make sure we don't match a postcode in a wrong country
            AND (       @Country IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
                    OR  @State IN ('MMM', 'NNN', 'OOO', 'PPP')
                )
            AND pd.Max_Distance <= 5000 -- within 5 km
    ) t
)
```

The above function works, but I would like to know if it can be improved. In particular, is it possible to force SQL Server to stop processing the `SELECT` statements after the first `SELECT` that returns a result-set (because we're interested in the first matching result only - `TOP 1`)?

**Update**

Thank you for suggestions thus far. I will add a `[Priority]` column as suggested in several answers and comments and an `ORDER BY` clause to ensure I get the top result.

I will also add a `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to the TVFN so SQL Server can parallelise the plan. While we're on this subject, the using a *multi-statement table-valued function* is a good idea (Thank you to [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137605/53380)), but multi-statement TVFN's always force a serial plan.

I will now try Lennart's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137608/53380), in which he suggested using a CTE.

Answer (score 9):

If you must use a single query (as required by a single inline function), you can use one of the two options below (illustrated in my recent answer to [Relating 2 tables with possible wildcards?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/137143)):

#### Option 1

Use multiple `APPLY` clauses with a startup condition for each using an outer reference from a previous apply in the chain. The efficiency of this method depends on the presence of startup filters in the execution plan. Correct results are guaranteed, but plan shape is not.

#### Option 2

Add an extra column with a constant literal to each clause of the union e.g. `[Priority] = 1` then add an `ORDER BY [Priority] ASC` at the `TOP (1)` scope. Efficient operation depends on the plan avoiding sorts.

On reflection, this is not what you want in this case, because one row from each option is required by the merge concatenation in the plan. Nevertheless, it is an option in more general situations (where the alternate inputs produce more than one row, and the first row at low cost).

---

In addition:

#### Option 3

Since you're only returning a single row, you could use a multi-statement table-valued function instead, with explicit logic to try each option in order (in separate queries), returning as soon as the first result is found. This is guaranteed to produce correct results efficiently.

**Note**

The current function is tecnhically nondeterministic; SQL Server could evaluate the union all in any order it chooses, potentially returning a lower-priority result before evaluating a higher priority one.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know sql-server well enough to state whether it works this way or not, but in theory there is no way you can say that one part of the union is evaluated before another. I.e. even though you have a perfect match, you may still end up with an approximate one.

You can however force this behavior by adding a priority to each part of the union and order by that. Something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
        -- Unique suburb-postcode-state combinations
        SELECT  1 as prio
                ,s.Suburb_DID
                ,s.Suburb
                ,s.State
                ,s.Postcode
                ,Geocode_DID = 4 -- Exact match by unique Postcode, Suburb and State
                ,s.Geocode_Latitude
                ,s.Geocode_Longitude
        FROM geocode.tSuburbs_XX s
        INNER JOIN [geocode].[tGeocode_Methods] gm
            ON s.Geocode_DID = gm.Geocode_DID

        WHERE s.[Is_Active] = 1
        AND s.[Suburb] = @Suburb
        AND s.[State] = @State
        AND s.[Postcode] = @Postcode
        -- Only suburbs that are geocoded with methods that can be used for geocoding customers
        AND gm.[Can_Use_For_VIP] = 1


        UNION ALL


        -- -- Unique suburb-postcode combinations
        SELECT  2 as prio
                ,s.Suburb_DID
                ,s.Suburb
                ,s.State
        [...]
) t
order by prio
```

Now you will get - one of - the row with the smallest prio in return. Note that the DBMS may still evaluate other options so there is no guarantee that it will perform better.

Another idea is to pipeline the parts via CTE's in the order of preference:

```
 with t1 as (
        -- Unique suburb-postcode-state combinations
        SELECT  1 as prio
                ,s.Suburb_DID
                ,s.Suburb
                ,s.State
                ,s.Postcode
                ,Geocode_DID = 4 -- Exact match by unique Postcode, Suburb and State
                ,s.Geocode_Latitude
                ,s.Geocode_Longitude
        FROM geocode.tSuburbs_XX s
        INNER JOIN [geocode].[tGeocode_Methods] gm
            ON s.Geocode_DID = gm.Geocode_DID

        WHERE s.[Is_Active] = 1
        AND s.[Suburb] = @Suburb
        AND s.[State] = @State
        AND s.[Postcode] = @Postcode
        -- Only suburbs that are geocoded with methods that can be used for geocoding customers
        AND gm.[Can_Use_For_VIP] = 1
), t2 as (
        - -- Unique suburb-postcode combinations
        SELECT  2 as prio
                ,s.Suburb_DID
                ,s.Suburb
                ,s.State
        [...]
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM T1 )
), t3 as (
        [...]
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM T2 )
)
select * from t1
union all
select * from t2
union all
[...]
```

The optimizer may be smart enough to understand where to stop. It is at least obligated to evaluate t1 before t2 and so forth.

Comment: *"It is at least obligated to evaluate t1 before t2 and so forth."* That might be correct but it is not obligated to evaluate t1 once (it may do it twice, once for the (select * from t2) and another one for the (select * from t1).

Comment: I would say that is obligated to evaluate t1 more than once as t1 is called more than once.  CTE is not materialized.

Comment: If the optimizer is clever enough to deduce that it does not have to that, that should be logically find. A trick that may or may not work in sql-server to force the materialization of a cte is to make a call to a non-deterministic function, such as rand() in the cte.

Answer (score 3):

Combine all queries using `LEFT OUTER JOINS` and use the resulting columns in reverse order as parameters of [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190349.aspx) function.
This function will evaluate all the parameters from left to right and take the first not null value.

Comment: I see 2 problems with this suggestion: a). this could work if I needed to return 1 column only, but I need to return 2 columns **at the very least**; b). if I use `LEFT JOIN` then T-SQL will definitely try to evaluate each join. I want it to _stop_ after the first `LEFT JOIN` would return a result.

Comment: a) You can use COALESCE for both the columns
b) The order of parameters you put in COALESCE will make sure that it doesn't consider other joins if you have value in the previous ones.

Comment: Strictly speaking the JOINS will be evaluated before COALESCE, so I don't think there is any guarantee that COALESCE will short-circuit the JOINS.

Comment: @Kunal, I cannot try sql-server at the moment but you can try something like: `select coalesce(t1.x, t2.x) from ( values (1, 1/1) ) t1 (a,x) left join ( values (1,1/0) ) t2(a,x) on t1.a = t2.a` to see if that works or if you get a division by zero.

Comment: @Lennart: Thanks a lot for your concern but if I were you in this case, I would use 
`select coalesce(t1.x, t2.x) from ( values (1, 1/NULLIF(1, 0)) ) t1 (a,x) left join ( values (1,1/NULLIF(0, 0)) ) t2(a,x) on t1.a = t2.a`

Comment: @Kunal, that's beside the point. I may have misunderstood you, but if your intention was to only evaluate the necessary joins that probably wont work. The division by zero is only there to demonstrate that the select is evaluated before the COALESCE.

Answer (score 1):

you can populate the table and check for rows

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F1 (@int int)
RETURNS @table table (col1 int, col2 varchar(10))
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
     --insert into @table values (@int, 'one');
     if((select count(*) from @table) > 0)
         return;
     insert into @table values (@int, 'two');
     return;
END;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.F1(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Paul White, Lennart and Kunal Chitkara for their answers.

Also, thanks to ypercubeᵀᴹ for being the first to point out that `ORDER BY` is required even when a `SELECT TOP 1 *` query consists of multiple `UNION`'ed subqueries.

### 4 Approaches

I compared performance of the query written in 4 different ways:

1. **Method 1**

*Ordered SELECT TOP 1 from UNION'ed subqueries*, which has this form:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
    subquery1
    UNION ALL
    subquery2
    UNION ALL
    ...
    subquery7
) t
ORDER BY [Preference]
```

2. **Method 2**

*Chained CTE's followed by SELECT FROM UNION'ed subqueries from CTE's*, which has this form:

```
WITH s AS (sharedQuery),
cte1 AS (subquery1),
cte1 AS (subquery2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM q1)
), ...
cte7 AS (subquery7
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 UNION ALL ... SELECT 1 FROM cte6)
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    cte1
    UNION ALL
    cte2
    UNION ALL
    ...
    cte7
) t
```

3. **Method 3**

*SELECT FROM COALESCE'ed fields based on LEFT JOIN'ed subqueries and a CTE*, which has this form:

```
WITH s AS (sharedQuery),
SELECT COALESCE(q1.A, q2.A, ... q7.A)
FROM (
    subquery1
) q1 LEFT JOIN (
    subquery2
) q2 ON 1=1
...
LEFT JOIN (
   subquery7
) q7 ON 1=1
```

4. **Method 4**

*SELECT FROM COALESCE'ed fields based on OUTER APPLY'ed subqueries and a CTE*, which has this form:

```
WITH s AS (sharedQuery),
SELECT COALESCE(q1.A, q2.A, ... q7.A)
FROM (
    subquery1
) q1 OUTER APPLY (
    subquery2
) q2
...
OUTER APPLY (
   subquery7
) q7
```

As performance was the main reason for this exercise, it was desirable that the queries be written in a way that allows SQL Server query optimizer to produce a **parallel plan**. I needed to be aware that:

- the TVFN is an *inline* one, rather than a *multi-statement* one
- the TVFN must contain `WITH SCHEMABINDING` constraint, which means that all objects (tables, views, etc) referenced by the TVFN must reside in the same database
- using `TOP` forces the zone (the [sub]query to which `TOP` applies) to be run serially
- calculated fields that are based on scalar UDF force the whole plan to be run serially

### Test method

```
-- Generate test data by loading some random addresses into a temporary table
SELECT TOP 1000 *
INTO #Addresses
FROM geocode.tDelivery_Address_Geocodes
ORDER BY NEWID()


-- Switch on statistics before running queries
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON

-- Clear cache before running each test
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

-- Use a SELECT and OUTER APPLY to run the TVFN under test:

SELECT *
FROM #Addresses a
OUTER APPLY [geocode].[tvfn_Customer_Geocode_From_Address2](a.Suburb, a.TownCityState, a.PostCode, a.Country) t
```

### Test results

```
==========================================================================
|          | CPU time| Elapsed |    | Est Subtree| Cached   | CPU Parse &|
| Method   | (s)     | time (s)| DOP| Cost       | plan size| Compile (s)|
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Method 1 | 16.427  | 16.508  | 1  | 50.4757    |  256 KB  | 0.186      |
| Method 2 | 86.908  | 86.996  | 1  | 1540.59    |  4048 KB | 5.241      |
| Method 3*| 28.641  | 28.802  | 0  | 254.32     |  352 KB  | 0.422      |
| Method 3 | 32.088  | 15.675  | 4  | 254.506    |  360 KB  | 0.422      |
| Method 4 | 24.710  | 24.878  | 1  | 205.314    |  304 KB  | 0.344      |
==========================================================================
```

Note:

- DOP = Degree of Parallelism
- Methods marked with a star* were executed with `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`

We can see from the results that **Method 1 was the fastest**, but it will always generate a serial plan (because it uses `TOP` in the outer-most query).

**Method 3** was slower when executed in a serial plan (`OPTION MAXDOP 1`), but was faster on a multi-CPU machine when executed in a parallel plan. Depending on the number of CPU's available on the server, this method may be the best option, especially if the query is run as part of a larger query that would also benefit from parallelism.

**Method 4** was also a good candidate, but I couldn't get SQL Server to generate a parallel plan for it.

**Method 2** was by far the slowest.

Comment: If you have the opportunity you can check if adding a rand() as dummy column in each of the cte's. Also, as ybercube pointed out it is sufficient to check for existence of the predessor alone. I.e. `cte7 AS (subquery7
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte6)`